# Host Infragistics Ultracombo in a Datagridview Cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, infragistics, ultracombo

Hi and happy year for all of you,

Like I said in the title I need to host an Infragistics Ultracombo inside a Datagridview Cell.

To host controls in a datagridview cell I use this [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) and it works fine for many controls but for some reason it doesn't work with Ultracombo

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the UltraCombo or would the UltraComboEditor work?  If the ultraComboEditor would work, you could use the UltraColumnComboEditor that Infragistics provides: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraDataGridView.UltraComboEditorColumn_members.html

Comment: If the UltraComboEditor doesn't work, can you post the code you are using for the custom column with the UltraCombo?

Comment: Well, There is no way to use ultracombo or ultracomboeditor in datagridview. Im using ultragrid now. I wanted ultracombo in DGV because i want multi-column combobox inside DGV.

Comment: The link I provided was to the UltraComboEditorColumn, I had mistyped it in the first comment and this would allow using the UltraComboEditor in the DataGridView.